# Running Modern Opengl on raspberry pi

Tags: c++, opengles

Is there any way to "enable" modern OpenGL on the Raspberry Pi (specifically the Raspberry Pi3)?

I would like to use C++ instead of Python, since I'm a lot more familiar with it. I know there is a way of creating graphics using pyOpenGL and pyGame, but I would like to know if it is possible (and how) to access "pure" OpenGL using the graphics drivers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your running the latest Raspbian Stretch with Desktop.

To enable OpenGL, from a terminal window:

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Select 'Advanced Options'

[image]

Select 'GL Driver'

[image]

Select 'GL (Full KMS)'

[image]

Then Reboot

To test it's working you can install and run glxgears - a graphical demo that should run at close to 60fps:

```
sudo apt-get -y install mesa-utils
glxgears
```

Comment: Yes, just google OpenGL C++ tutorial.

Comment: According to a [Raspberry Pi engineer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=244582#p1493241), it's better to use Fake KMS.