# Running Opengl application on pi 2b, frame issues. Pi issues, or optimization problems?

Tags: pi-3, pi-2

Here is my application that I have managed to get running on my pi.

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

vertices = (
    ( 1, -1, -1),
    ( 1,  1, -1),
    (-1,  1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    ( 1, -1,  1), 
    ( 1,  1,  1), 
    (-1, -1,  1), 
    (-1,  1,  1)
)
edges = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7)
)
surfaces = (
    (0, 1, 2, 3),
    (3, 2, 7, 6),
    (6, 7, 5, 4),
    (4, 5, 1, 0), 
    (1, 5, 7, 2), 
    (4, 0, 3, 6)
)
colors = (
    (1, 0, 0), 
    (0, 1, 0), 
    (1, 0.5, 0), 
    (0, 0, 1), 
    (1, 1, 0), 
    (1, 1, 1)
)

class Cube():
    def __init__(self, id, N, scale):
        self.i = -1
        self.N = N
        self.scale = scale
        self.initI = [i - (N // 2) for i in id]
        self.currentI = [i - (N // 2) for i in id]
        self.rot = [[1 if i == j else 0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]

    def isAffected(self, axis, slice, dir):
        return self.currentI[axis] == slice - (self.N // 2)

    def update(self, axis, slice, dir):

        if not self.isAffected(axis, slice, dir):
            return

        i, j = (axis + 1) % 3, (axis + 2) % 3
        for k in range(3):
            self.rot[k][i], self.rot[k][j] = -self.rot[k][j] * dir, self.rot[k][i] * dir

        self.currentI[i], self.currentI[j] = -self.currentI[j] * dir, self.currentI[i] * dir

    def draw(self, col, surf, vert, animate, angle, axis, slice, dir):

        pos = [(p - (self.N % 1) / 2) * 2.1 * self.scale for p in self.currentI]
        rotMat = [*self.rot[0], 0, *self.rot[1], 0, *self.rot[2], 0, *pos, 1]

        glPushMatrix()
        if animate and self.isAffected(axis, slice, dir):
            glRotatef(angle * dir, *[1 if i == axis else 0 for i in range(3)])
        glMultMatrixf(rotMat) 
        glScalef(self.scale, self.scale, self.scale)

        glBegin(GL_QUADS)
        for i in range(len(surf)): #change for loop to only iterate according to outside colour surfaces
            #inplement function that will iterate through array and return a number to colour
            glColor3fv(colors[i]) #change i to an iterable that maps colour to arrayofvalues colour
            for j in surf[i]:
                glVertex3fv(vertices[j])
        glEnd()

        glPopMatrix()

class EntireCube(MotorControl):
    def __init__(self, N, scale):
        MotorControl.__init__(self)
        self.N = N
        cr = range(self.N)
        self.cubes = [Cube((x, y, z), self.N, scale) for x in cr for y in cr for z in cr]

    def mainloop(self):
        rotateUpKey, rotateDownKey, rotateLeftKey, rotateRightKey = False, False, False, False
        rotationalSensitivity = 2
        rotateWholeCube = 5

        rotCubeMap  = { K_UP: (-1, 0), K_DOWN: (1, 0), K_LEFT: (0, -1), K_RIGHT: (0, 1)}
        rotSliceMap = {
            K_1: (0, 0, 1),
            # K_2: (0, 1, 1),
            K_3: (0, 2, 1), 
            K_4: (1, 0, 1), 
            # K_5: (1, 1, 1),
            K_6: (1, 2, 1), 
            K_7: (2, 0, 1), 
            # K_8: (2, 1, 1), 
            K_9: (2, 2, 1),
            K_q: (0, 0, -1), 
            # K_w: (0, 1, -1), 
            K_e: (0, 2, -1), 
            K_r: (1, 0, -1), 
            # K_t: (1, 1, -1),
            K_y: (1, 2, -1), 
            K_u: (2, 0, -1), 
            # K_i: (2, 1, -1), 
            K_o: (2, 2, -1),
        }  

        angX, angY, rotCube = 0, 0, (0, 0)
        animate, animateAng, animateSpeed = False, 0, 5
        action = (0, 0, 0)
        while True:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key in rotCubeMap:
                        rotCube = rotCubeMap[event.key]
                    if not animate and event.key in rotSliceMap:
                        MotorControl.OrganiseMotorInput(self, str(pygame.key.name(event.key)))
                        animate, action = True, rotSliceMap[event.key]
                if event.type == KEYUP:
                    if event.key in rotCubeMap:
                        rotCube = (0, 0)

            angX += rotateWholeCube * rotCube[0]
            angY += rotateWholeCube * rotCube[1]

            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
            glLoadIdentity()
            glTranslatef(0, 0, -40)
            glRotatef(angY, 0, 1, 0)
            glRotatef(angX, 1, 0, 0)

            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

            if animate:
                if animateAng >= 90:
                    for cube in self.cubes:
                        cube.update(*action)
                    animate = False
                    animateAng = 0

            for cube in self.cubes:
                cube.draw(colors, surfaces, vertices, animate, animateAng, *action)
            if animate:
                animateAng += animateSpeed

            pygame.display.flip()
            pygame.time.wait(10)

def main():

    pygame.init()
    display = (800,600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) 

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

    NewEntireCube = EntireCube(3, 1.5) 
    NewEntireCube.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```

Now I know I could optimize this a lot (only loading colours/vertex/surface/etc that are shown ie, only loading a 2d image of cube.

I have seen that the pi can run quake, so i'm wondering why this won't handle this simple application. I haven't exactly looked after my pi... and it seems to always have the 'need power' symbol which is a little annoying

Is there something I can do without changing this code to make it run smoothly?

Overclocking? optimize code? Pi 3? Faulty pi2b? Some other setting somewhere? Is this running smoothly for you?

Comment: What power supply are you using? Have you enabled the GL driver (Full KMS) in raspi-config ?

Comment: Have used multiple usb cables, multiple transformers, don't actually know what it came with to be honest. I think it is a bit buggy. I haven't enabled the GL driver, will do that now.

Comment: Buy the official power supply https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/

Comment: I don't see any gl driver options under raspberry pi configuration.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75071/running-modern-opengl-on-raspberry-pi

Comment: `raspi-config` go to `advanced options` ... it's the LAST option ... and if you don't have that, may I suggest `sudo apt get update && sudo apt get dist-upgrade`

Comment: I'm having issues with booting after following instructions in the thread, flickering screen on boot into raspbian...

Comment: which instructions did you follow? have you tried increasing GPU memory? (i.e. Memory Split in the Advanced menu) What is your current Memory Split?

Comment: Full KMS, unfortunately.

Comment: Well I increased it to 800mb, I think. Which is probably too high, I'm having to reinstall raspbian as I can't boot. Do you recommend using legacy gl instead of full KMS?

Comment: No need to reinstall raspbian - just edit the config.txt in the boot partition (readable in windows) andd change the GPU_MEM it to a reasonable level ... what WAS the memory split? 256 is recommended

Comment: I'm not sure, I adjusted it through the gui version of rasp config, so it only allowed/showed gpu memory adjustment. I adjusted it to 800mb and closed the window. Tried setting the drivers to full KMS and can't boot.

Comment: `so it only allowed/showed gpu memory` - yes, so what was it before you changed it ... anyway ... you don't need to reinstall raspbian just fix config.txt

Comment: Sweet as, don't think I have changed it before, so stock? 50 ish? Thinking back, was probably being a bit stupid hahaha

Comment: I have changed config file, still doing the same thing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm just having power problems... Will get a powersupply and get back to you...

Comment: dont' only look for `gpu_mem` - look for `gpu_mem_1024` - and set that to something meaningful  ... or do you mean it's still stuttering

Comment: Ok so I managed to get it to boot, I reduced the overclock... Which was causing my power issue( I didn't realise I had overclocked=p) Im running glx gears with 60fps, but my application still runs slowly  on full KMS

Comment: I have increase gpu memory split to 128mb